# How to make a ToolStripComboBox look like a regular ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am dynamically adding a ToolStripComboBox, and I need it to look like a regular combo box.

The tool strip version has the editable field and looks completely different. Is there a property (or multiple properties) I need to set to make it look and feel like the default combo box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set property `FlatStyle` to `FlatStyle.Standard`; this will give you the same dropdown arrow button.

Set property `DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`; this will make it so that you can select but not edit.

---

In Visual Studio designer it would be setting the property to *DropDownList*:

[image: Screenshot of setting property DropDownStyle of a ToolStripComboBox to 'DropDownList'.]